# Datamapper "Update" does not update record

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I am having trouble with datamapper not updating a model. I can create and save models without issue. I have enabled `raise_on_save_failure` and checked the return value of `update` but see no errors.

Here is the model:

```
class UserProfile   
  include DataMapper::Resource  
  attr_accessor :id, :wants_hints, :is_beta_user  
  property :id, Serial #auto-increment integer key  
  property :is_beta_user, Boolean  
  property :wants_hints, Boolean  
  has 1, :user, :through => Resource 
end
```

And here is where it is updated in the controller:

```
if user = User.get(request.session[:user])      
  if request.params[:user_profile]        
    beta = request.params[:user_profile].has_key?('is_beta_user')        
    hints = request.params[:user_profile].has_key?('wants_hints')        
    user.user_profile.update({:is_beta_user => beta, :wants_hints => hints}) # returns true
    Log.puts user.user_profile.errors.each {|e| Log.puts e.to_s} # returns empty list []
  end    
end
```

When the controller is called `update` always returns true, and there are never errors in the error list. The datamapper log, which is set to `:debug`, only shows the `SELECT` queries for retrieving the `user` and `user_profile` and that is all. Why would I be able to `save` a newly created model, but not be allowed to `update` that same model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `attr_accessor` fixed the problem. From my research `attr_accessor` is used for attributes not in the database.

Answer (score 1):

DataMapper's `save` and `update` do not necessarily produce an `UPDATE` sentence. It will only do so if the data held by the model object has changed. So, for example, in the following code the `update` will return `true` but will not produce an `UPDATE`:

```
# This generates an INSERT
user = User.create(:login => 'kintaro', :email => 'kintaro@example.com')

# This does NOT generate an UPDATE
user.update(:login => 'kintaro')
```

If you do this, however, an `UPDATE` will be produced:

```
# This generates an UPDATE
user.update(:login => 'kintaro22')
```

Maybe this is what's happening?

Comment: Checked and double checked. It is definitely updating attributes to new values.